# When is it a good idea to make a DLL file

Tags: c#, .net, dll

So, I have searched stack for a similar question, without finding anything.
So tell me if this is a duplicate.

Anyway,
What my question is as described in the title.

When is it a good idea to make a .dll file.

For instance, whenever I start on a new project, I notice that in many cases I have to re-write the same\similar code over again, especially when it come to database connections, opening, closing, running queries and reading\writing files.

Is it good practice to create a dll for such small tasks, or could it lead to bigger problems?

Any suggestions on when to create dll files would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: (In C#) you make a DLL file when you compile an assembly with the appropriate properties. I think you are asking, when should a new project or assembly be created? This answer is subjective and influenced by multiple factors, not stated in your question.

Comment: You are asking a very broad topic. Let's try to shrink it down. Authors of frameworks mainly create dlls, as well as authors of libraries. So, some lines of code have to be changed once. If You have some projects with similar code-sections, You just are free to encapsulate those functions into an own dll. So You also will have to alter code only once. It usually could lead to more problems, because You should make the encapsulation more or less a kind of generic, so that the calling applications are running the encapsulated methods properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are after is [code reusability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_reuse), which is a broader subject than making DLL's, which as @Jodrell said, is created when you compile an assembly. The idea of re using code is something which spans across multiple domains and is not thus strictly related to the .NET platform. You could for instance have a .JAR file (in Java) which provides you with a set of common functionalities as well.

Code re usability *when done right* helps productivity and reduces development time of certain modules since certain components have already been developed and tested. These components are usually segments of systems which are common throughout a series of projects, such as Database connectivity, logging, etc.

Components destined to be re used might have a longer development time though, so as to ensure that the designed module is flexible enough to cater future situations.

Answer (score 1):

Make a DLL with functions that you need to add to many projects. Just like you said. I have one with lots of string functions, e.g. generating MD5 hashes, random passwords, stripping HTML tags, etc. I also have a DLL project for custom ASP.NET user management and authentication.

Identify things that you do a lot, then try and put them in a reusable project and compile it to a DLL.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the best condition to create a dll file is when you have basic but repetitive functions that you will be using.
It also co;es in handy when you need the function across different programming platforms.
This will avoid you to re-write the same function for a different language.

Example would be, you can have a C# code and VB.NET code. You can create a dll file for the common functions used by both applications and then simply call them within each app, rather than writing the function for the C# app, then re-write it for the VB.NET app.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, an assembly should group functionalities that you want to reference in other projects as a unit. If an assembly contains disparate functions that are not related, consumers will not have the option to choose just the parts they want. Conversely, if associated functionality is spread across many assemblies consumers will have the burden of adding multiple references to do one thing.

The choice of what should be grouped into an assembly depends on what is coded and who will use it.